# Is StringBuffer the Kotlin way to handle multiple string concatenation like in java?

Tags: string, kotlin, stringbuffer

What would be the kotlin way to handle multiple string concatenation?

--edit--
placing the piece of code that led me to this doubt

```
fun getNCharsFromRange(n: Int, range: CharRange): String {
    val chars = range.toList()
    val buffer = StringBuffer()
    while (buffer.length < n) {
        val randomInt = Random.Default.nextInt(0, chars.lastIndex)
        val newchar = chars[randomInt]
        val lastChar = buffer.lastOrNull() ?: ""
        if (newchar != lastChar) {
            buffer.append(newchar)
        }
    }
    return buffer.toString()
}
```

Comment: just use [string templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates) and the compiler will use a StringBuilder under the hood

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem I'm not sure templating would fit well with my case, so I just added the piece of code that led me to this doubt

Comment: I think using StringBuilder or StringBuffer is correct in this case, regardless using kotlin or Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is the standard way to construct a String in Kotlin, as in Java.

(Unless it can be done in one line, of course, where a [string template](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#using-string-templates) is usually better than Java-style concatenation.)

Kotlin has one improvement, though: you can use [`buildString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/build-string.html) to handle that implicitly, which can make the code a little more concise.  For example, your code can be written as:

```
fun getNCharsFromRange(n: Int, range: CharRange): String {
    val chars = range.toList()
    return buildString {
        while (length < n) {
            val randomInt = Random.Default.nextInt(0, chars.lastIndex)
            val newChar = chars[randomInt]
            val lastChar = lastOrNull() ?: ""
            if (newChar != lastChar)
                append(newChar)
        }
    }
}
```

That has no mention of `buffer`: instead, `buildString` creates a StringBuilder, makes it available as `this`, and then returns the resulting String.  (So `length`, `lastOrNull()`, and `append` refer to the StringBuilder.)

For short code, this can be significantly more concise and clearer; though the benefits are much less clear with longer code.  (Your code may be in the grey area between…)

---

Worth pointing out that the function name is misleading: it avoids repeated characters, but allows duplicates that are not consecutive.  If that's deliberate, then it would be worth making clear in the function name (and/or its doc comment).  Alternatively, if the intent is to avoid *all* duplicates, then there's an approach which is much simpler and/or more efficient: to shuffle the range (or at least part of it).

Using existing library functions, and making it an extension function on CharRange, the whole thing could be as simple as:

```
fun CharRange.randomChars(n: Int) = shuffled().take(n).joinToString("")
```

That shuffles the whole list, even if only a few characters are needed.  So it would be even more efficient to shuffle just the part needed.  But there's no library function for that, so you'd have to write that manually.  I'll leave it as an exercise!

Comment: yes I'm supposed to avoid only consecutive char from being the same with this method. 
it's in the middle of a password generator exercise with min constraints of num of digits, num of uppers, num of lowers and total length. 
This method is being used to generate uppers, lowers and digits separately and then I'm shuffling all three together and re-shuffling if there are consecutive equal chars. if I don't constraint the generation on the parts i wouldn't be able to guarantee the re-shuffling to end in the worst case

Comment: but my real doubt was how to concatenate the strings the best kotlin way. I'm still relying mainly on my java knowledge to code kotlin